# can't download google eclipse plugin. dl.google.com having problems?

Tags: google-app-engine

Apologies..., but I'm not really certain where to direct this question...

I've been trying to install the google plugin for eclipse (4.2) from:

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

but it looks like the repo is having problems.

Eclipse reports the following upon an attempted install:

"No software site found at:  https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2"

I appear to have routability to the site..., can connect with..., but no joy.

My other Eclipse instances that already have the plugin installed also fail an "Update" check when attempting to access the repo..., though access to all other repos succeeds.

This started happening maybe late y'day morning or early afternoon.  The repo did seem to become accessible for a brief time, but then went away again.

And just to be clear..., yup, I'm doing this in the context of GAE development.

Thx! -- John

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `https` use just `http` as given in the intructions [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2)
I have installed in this morning and it worked fine.
Try this:

```
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
```

Even `https` worked for me checked just now. May be problem with internet connection. If your are using proxy, check whether its configured properly for Eclipse.

Comment: Thx Vivek.  I had tried that y'day (and just now again), but no luck.  No proxy is involved..., traceroute seems OK..., dunno.

Comment: It does SEEM like a networking problem of some sort.  It's kind of intermittent.  It fails continuously on a Mac..., and most of the time w/ a Linux box.  It's odd that it's this one repo that is a problem...  I wonder if it works for some because they're requesting from a different region and get routed to a different server...???

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse from a local update archive

offline plugin

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip